# Write a method to print out a string "Name" multiple times 

Tags: java, string, loops, accumulator

I am answering a question for an Intro to Programming class and cannot - after reading through my notes, Big Java book, and looking online - find out where to begin.

It seems as though it should be very simple, but I just need to get started.  All of this is for Java and is being worked on in Eclipse.

The task is to take in a name ("Name") and a number (int x) and display the "Name" x number of times on one line, x-1 times on another line, and so on and so on until you display the name only once.  It seems like it should be a reverse accumulator, but I'm having trouble starting my method.  How do I begin?  I know I can't multiply strings in Java like you can in python or other languages, but how can I print the "Name" x number of times without building an Array or inputing

```
System.out.println("name" + " " + "name" + " "...).
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.  I am a novice at this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need a *loop*, a common feature of programming languages.

Have a close look at the java [`for`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop.

Additional hint:

`System.out.println("test")` prints it's argument in a single line while `System.out.print("test")` doesn't add a `CR/LF` after `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [java flow control statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html). The `for` and `while` constructs would allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`.

Here is the sample code: (not the actual code which you want, just a SAMPLE)

```
import java.io.*;

public class StringNameTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            String strNumber = "";
            String strName = "";
            int intNumber;
            try 
            {
                //  open up standard input
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                //  prompt the user to enter their name
                System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
                strName = br.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter the number of times you want to print your name: ");
                strNumber = br.readLine();
                intNumber = Integer.parse(strNumber);

                for (row = 0; row < intNumber; row++)
                {
                    for(col = 0; col < intNumber; col++)
                        System.out.print(strName + " ");

                    System.out.println("");
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }


    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Providing complete code for a homework assignment doesn't leave much room for learning.

Comment: It is wrong as well... The OP wanted a triangle of names. Your code does generate a square...

Comment: @rsp - it is just a sample, not doing exactly what is being demanded - still some room for learning. (this should have been explained in the answer).

Comment: @Martijn - that is OK since it's only a sample, we should not do the (whole) homework.

Comment: yes, i should have mentioned in the answer that its just a sample and not the complete working code as the user was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method gets a string with the name and a count. Using one for loop to count and another to repeat the name value, you should be able to get the output you're after.

`System.out` is a printstream and it has both `println()` to output a line ended with a linebreak and `print()` to output a string without ending it with a linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer loop that counts to x and an inner loop that counts to (x - outer loop counter). Be aware of the common "one off" error.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that Java doesn't have built-in String repetition. But you can define your own method that does exactly this.

```
public static String repeated(String s, int times) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  // TODO: append /s/ to /sb/ for /times/ times.
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Good point for you that you want to use this "operator" instead of putting together everything into one large block of code. This helps to keep your programs readable.

Comment: but he wants to show "s" --> for "times" on first line; then "s" --> for "times - 1" on second line and so on.. Your code would display on the same line..

Comment: No, it wouldn't. My code doesn't show anything per se, it is just a little helper method, so that he can build his expressions easier.

Answer (score 0):

First thought: you need `n` lines. So, enter a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
```

Then: you need to print on line `i` the string `n - i` times. Enter a nested loop:

```
     for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j)
     {
```

Then start off printing the name:

```
           System.out.print(name + " ");
     }
```

Notice I didn't use `println`, because we want all the names on the same line.
Now you need to end the line when we printed `n - i` times:

```
     System.out.println();
```

Close our outer-loop:

```
}
```

---

And if you don't know how to make the program ask the name and the integer `n` to the user:

```
String name = null;
int n = 0;
try
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
    name = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("How many times (n): ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1); // exit!, there was an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int i = 0;
        int j = 20;

   for(i = 1; i <= j; i++){

          System.out.println("My Name");


   } //ends for loop

     // use system.out.print("") for same line 


}    //ends static void main

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
int y = 1;

x = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
        System.out.print("O");
    }
    System.out.println();
    ++y;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's nice to see that someone cares about older questions. However your answer does the exact opposite of what was asked. The `i` loops should be inversed (`int i=x; i>0; i--`). In addition it would be much appreciated if you could add some comments on what this code means and why it works the way it should.. etc.. code only answers won't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WithoutLoop
{
      static int count;
   public static void repeat(String s)
   {
       while(count <= 10)
       {
           System.out.println(s);
           count++;
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        repeat("hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: if count is 10, String will be printed 10 times. this is the simplest one to print number of times without looping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see your comment, but It's best to include some explanation with the answer and not just post code.

Comment: An answer should be more than just a code snippet. Please edit your answer to include an explanation relevant to the question.

Comment: You need to update the answer with details. Your answer does use loop (while loop)